# Macro for Graphing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in Excel that graphs numbers on a line plot. If you click on a particular cell in the A column, the macro is supposed to draw a line plot of the numbers next to it.

Here is the code for the macro:

```
Sub Graph1()
'
' Graph1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Range("A1:D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet'!$J$4:$M$4")
End Sub
```

When I try to run this macro for cell A2, for example, I get the graph associated with cell A1. This happens with all other cells. So if I run the macro for cell A10, I get the graph associated with cell A1. How would I Fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You forced the source to be a fixed range ($J$4:$M$4) instead of activecell. Try below code with assumptions:

1. The data source consists of only 1 row, 4 columns starting from activecell
2. Only use first Chart Object, if there isn't one then create one and use it

**Code:**

```
Sub Graph1()
'
' Graph1 Macro
'

'
    Dim oRng As Range, oCht As Chart
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oRng = ActiveCell.Range("A1:D1")
    oRng.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oCht Is Nothing Then Set oCht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    If oCht.ChartType <> xlLine Then oCht.ChartType = xlLine
    oCht.SetSourceData Source:=oRng
    Set oCht = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```